# mysql process crashed，errorlog prompt "[InnoDB] Assertion failure: buf0buf.h:1203:m_space != nullptr thread"

Tags: mysql, crash

one day mysql server has died suddenly, there is no anything from sys’log;
then i find the log of mysql , the following is the log error content:

```
InnoDB] Assertion failure: buf0buf.h:1203:m_space != nullptr thread 140506604328704
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
01:42:13 UTC - mysqld got signal 6 ;
Most likely, you have hit a bug, but this error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
Thread pointer: 0x7fc9dc6282a0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 7fca3e3d4c70 thread_stack 0x100000
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace(unsigned char const*, unsigned long)+0x3d) [0x1fc33ad]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x30b) [0xee902b]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0xf630) [0x7fcb50228630]
/lib64/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x37) [0x7fcb4e772387]
/lib64/libc.so.6(abort+0x148) [0x7fcb4e773a78]
/usr/sbin/mysqld() [0xc3378c]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(Buf_fetch_normal::get(buf_block_t*&)+0x1b8) [0x22ab088]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(Buf_fetch<Buf_fetch_normal>::single_page()+0x53) [0x22ab123]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(buf_page_get_gen(page_id_t const&, page_size_t const&, unsigned long, buf_block_t*, Page_fetch, char const*, unsigned long, mtr_t*, bool)+0x1ce) [0x22adade]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(btr_cur_search_to_nth_level(dict_index_t*, unsigned long, dtuple_t const*, page_cur_mode_t, unsigned long, btr_cur_t*, unsigned long, char const*, unsigned long, mtr_t*)+0x61d) [0x228f0fd]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(Row_sel_get_clust_rec_for_mysql::operator()(row_prebuilt_t*, dict_index_t*, unsigned char const*, que_thr_t*, unsigned char const**, unsigned long**, mem_block_info_t**, dtuple_t const**, mtr_t*, lob::undo_vers_t*)+0x115) [0x21d8225]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(row_search_mvcc(unsigned char*, page_cur_mode_t, row_prebuilt_t*, unsigned long, unsigned long)+0x208b) [0x21dcd2b]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(ha_innobase::general_fetch(unsigned char*, unsigned int, unsigned int)+0x2a9) [0x20bb0b9]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handler::ha_index_next_same(unsigned char*, unsigned char const*, unsigned int)+0x2f9) [0xff5b49]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(RefIterator<false>::Read()+0x11b) [0xd5d51b]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(FilterIterator::Read()+0x14) [0x1290aa4]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(Query_expression::ExecuteIteratorQuery(THD*)+0x29e) [0xe6bbbe]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(Query_expression::execute(THD*)+0x2f) [0xe6bf1f]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(Sql_cmd_dml::execute(THD*)+0x186) [0xdf44f6]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(mysql_execute_command(THD*, bool)+0x9c8) [0xd9c618]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(dispatch_sql_command(THD*, Parser_state*)+0x412) [0xd9fdc2]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(dispatch_command(THD*, COM_DATA const*, enum_server_command)+0xe0e) [0xda10ee]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(do_command(THD*)+0x194) [0xda3194]
/usr/sbin/mysqld() [0xed9c70]
/usr/sbin/mysqld() [0x248d620]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0x7ea5) [0x7fcb50220ea5]
/lib64/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d) [0x7fcb4e83ab0d]
```

the firsttime, i restart mysql server, but several days later, the pheneomenon is repeated

i could not get any result

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
OS, Version? 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
Additional very helpful OS information includes - please,  
htop            1st page, if available, TERMINATE, 
top -b -n 1  for most active apps, 
top -b -n 1 -H  for details on your mysql threads memory and cpu usage, 
ulimit -a       for list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device & core/cpu count, 
df -h  for Used - Free space by device, 
df -i  for inode info by device, 
free -h  for Used - Free  Mem: and Swap:, 
cat /proc/meminfo includes VMallocUused,  
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.